# € char is shown as ? in UTF8 Output

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml, utf-8

I have reworked a website and now it is xhtml valid etc and using UTF8. Everything is fine, but if anywhere in the Database is a Euro-char it is just displayed as a questionmark.

What would be the right way to fix this?
As output is done by Typo3 i cant change much about that.

Comment: Does this only happen with the € sign or with other characters like e.g. ω (small omega, utf8: 0xCF 0x89), too?

Answer (score 5):

Try executing these queries *before* the queries that fetch data:

```
SET NAMES utf8
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: If you're using the php/mysql extension (mysql_connect, mysql_query, ...) and PHP 5 >= 5.2.3 better use mysql_set_charset(), otherwise mysql_real_escape_string() doesn't "know" about the change of the encoding. see http://php.net/mysql_set_charset

Answer (score 4):

This might be due to wrong database connection encoding

Lookup SET NAMES sql statement

```
    $db_link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';", $db_link);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';", $db_link);
```

Answer (score 2):

**DON'T issue both statements!**

Don't issue

```
SET NAMES utf8
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

one after another. It can cause trouble. I already had bad experience with SET CHARACTER SET utf8 right after SET NAMES utf8.

I recommend to issue only `SET NAMES ...`

MySQL docs has explanations why: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

In short: `SET NAMES ...` sets connection's charset to the same as client ans result charset. while `SET CHARACTER NAME...` sets different connection's charset and collation.

Please read the doc and decide whichever it better in your case. Or even better make a test.

Answer (score 2):

What charset (encoding, collation,...) are you using for the database column that contains the € sign?

The problem could be that your data stored in this column ist mixed up because the € sign is a somehow difficult beast when not using UTF-8 character encoding. The problem ist that the € sign is encoded as `\xA4` when using ISO-8859-15 and as `\x80` when using Windows-1252 (the common Western-European charset on Windows machines).
If your data inside the column is not encoded correctly MySQL won't be able to transcode it into UTF-8 correctly - even if you use `SET NAMES utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you have the right character data (`0x20AC`), it could also be the fonts ont he client-side. If the font you are using does not handle that particular character, you'll just see some default question mark.

However, why not use the escape code `&euro;`, which gives you: €

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
$value = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $value);
```

The "ISO-8859-1" part may be different depending on your MySQL table character encoding.